# Children Component undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

See the below function i am creating the Auth routes and getting the children undefined and shows blank page. In App.js i am using the private route as you can see below and when i use simple Route instead of PrivateRoute its shows the Login component

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/" name="Login" render={props => <Login {...props}/>} />
```

Here is is My PrivateRoute.js. When i console the children its shows undefined

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
const token = cookie.get('token');
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        !token ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/dashboard",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
export default Private Route;
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are not sending the children component, so it would never see the children props.

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeReis see my Private Route i am send my props but its not receiving in the PrivateRoute

Comment: It seems for me that you are not passing the children and the children is not a component there

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like it. Let me know if it works for you.

Here is my privateRoute.js component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import { isAuthenticated } from 'auth';

export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={
      props => (
        isAuthenticated() ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
          )
      )} />
  );
}
```

Here I have another file in the root auth.js:

```
export const isAuthenticated = () =>  {
  return Boolean(localStorage.getItem('jwttoken'));
}

export const login = ({email, password}) => {
  // Logic
 localStorage.setItem('jwttoken', 'jkdsalkfj');
  return true;
}

export const logout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('jwttoken');
}
```

You can call it like:

```
<PrivateRoute
  component={ProjectPage}
  path="/project/:id"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Children refer to what's inside the tag

```
<PrivateRoute>
    <PrivateComponent/>
</PrivateRouter>
```

Here your children would be `<PrivateComponent/>`

You're not passing anything inside your PrivateRoute in your example. So you'll have undefined